# Comparing two strings in parallel

Tags: python, pattern-matching, sequence

I have two **sorted** text files which both contain the protein sequences of the **same** 600 samples, just that we use different methods to obtain the sequences. Now, we want to compare the sequences in both files to see if they agree with each other.

This is a **high throughput sequence alignment/comparison**, so I would like to write a small script to **process all sequences in parallel**, meaning to compare:

**sequence 1 in file 1 with sequence 1 in file 2,**

**sequence 2 in file 1 with sequence 2 in file 2 and so on.**

And then eventually return me the results, whether it's matching or not matching, and give me the % identity.

Each sequence has an associated header, indicated with a ">" followed by the sample name.

```
file1
>Sample 1
ABCDEFG
>Sample 2
ZXCVBNM
>Sample 3
QAZWSXEDC
>Sample 4
ZXCVSDFGHNMJKL

file2
>Sample 1
ABCDEFG
>Sample 2
ZXCVBOM
>Sample 3
QAZWSXEDCF
>Sample 4
ASDFGHJK
```

I would like to generate a table to show the results in the following format:

```
Sample Name   Seq 1           Seq 2           Mismatch   % Identity
Sample 1      ABCDEFG         ABCDEFG         0          100
Sample 2      ZXCVBNM         ZXCVBOM         1          85.7
Sample 3      QAZRWSXED       QAZWSXEDCF      2          80
Sample 4      ZXCVSDFGHNMJKL  ASDFGHJK        6          42.9
```

I was thinking to do it this way (attaching pseudocode here):

```
with open ('file1.txt', 'r') as infile1:
    sanger = infile1.read().splitlines()  # Read file1 in

with open ('file2.txt', 'r') as infile2:
    ngs = infile2.read().splitlines()   # Read file2 in

with open ('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:  # Write output file
    data_iter = iter(sequences)
    order = ['Sample Name', 'Seq 1', 'Seq 2', 'Mismatch', '% Identity']
    header = '\t'.join([k for k in order])
    outfile.write(header + '\n')   # Print the header information

    if sanger[1] in ngs[1]:
        locations = [[{'Sample Name': seq_name.strip('>'),
                       'Seq 1': sanger[1],
                       'Seq 2': ngs[1],
                       'Mismatch': mismatch count,
                       '% Identity': 100 - (mismatch count/len(sanger/ngs) * 100)}]]                        
        for loc in chain.from_iterable(locations):
            output = '\t'.join([str(loc[k]) for k in order])
            outfile.write(output + '\n')
```

And repeat for all 60 sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loading both files, you may want to open them and iterate trough them with the zip function and the file included iterator. This should work:

`for element_in_file1, element un file1 in zip(open(file1), open(file2)):
    #extract logic in function`

you rmain logic should be in a function which would compute the alignment and results and return the output string.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your main question how to process your two files efficiently. The tacked on questions about metrics and building a table are separate and should be dealt with in separate questions.

1. Open the files.
2. `zip` them together
3. Pipe the iterator through [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) with a step size of two.

Demo:

```
$ cat file1.txt 
>Sample 1
ABCDEFG
>Sample 2
ZXCVBNM
>Sample 3
QAZWSXEDC
>Sample 4
ZXCVSDFGHNMJKL
$ cat file2.txt 
>Sample 1
ABCDEFG
>Sample 2
ZXCVBOM
>Sample 3
QAZWSXEDCF
>Sample 4
ASDFGHJK
$ python3
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> 
>>> with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2:
...     pairs = islice(zip(f1, f2), 1, None, 2)
...     for pair in pairs:
...         print(pair)
... 
('ABCDEFG\n', 'ABCDEFG\n')
('ZXCVBNM\n', 'ZXCVBOM\n')
('QAZWSXEDC\n', 'QAZWSXEDCF\n')
('ZXCVSDFGHNMJKL\n', 'ASDFGHJK\n')
```

This assumes your are using Python 3, use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) over `zip` in Python 2 in order to avoid reading both files into memory completely.